# nslookup: can't resolve kubernetes.default

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I am trying to learn DNS in kubernetes with https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

1. I deployed the busybox
2. `kubectl get pods busybox -o wide`

   ```
   NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
   busybox   1/1       Running   0          16m       10.200.1.5   worker-1
   ```
3. `kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default`

   ```
   Server:    10.32.0.10
   Address 1: 10.32.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

   nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
   command terminated with exit code 1
   ```
4. Do I need to modify the /etc/resolv.conf file of the worker-1 node. currently the /etc/resolv.conf content is below

   ```
   nameserver 169.254.169.254
   search c.k8s-project-193906.internal google.internal**
   ```
5. Also the version of the worker-1
   lsb_release -a
   No LSB modules are available.
   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
   Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
   Release:    18.04
   Codename:   bionic

Please help me figure out which configuration causes the resolve error.  Do I need to change resolve.conf file and based on what?

Comment: Can you please provide some more information on where do you try to do that? Is this somewhere in the Cloud (if yes which one) or on-premise Kubernetes? I can tell it is not a minikube so what tool did you use to deploy the cluster?

Answer (score 21):

You have encountered a bug in the latest versions of the busybox docker image.  Use the tag `busybox:1.28` instead of `latest`. This [bug link is here](https://github.com/docker-library/busybox/issues/48):

```
"Nslookup does not work in latest busybox image"
"1.27/1.28 are working , 1.29/1.29.1 are not"
```

Here it is **failing** with the `busybox:latest` tag.

```
$ kubectl run busybox --image busybox:latest --restart=Never --rm -it busybox -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN

*** Can't find kubernetes.default: No answer
/ # exit
pod "busybox" deleted
```

Here's the same command **succeeding** with the `busybox:1.28` tag.

```
$ kubectl run busybox --image busybox:1.28 --restart=Never --rm -it busybox -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes.default
Address 1: 10.96.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
/ # exit
pod "busybox" deleted
```

Comment: nslookup for my service is working inside a busybox but its not working directly what is the reason?? @David

Comment: @DavidW: Thanks, man! I have googled for 2h hours about the error in DNS and found it in busybox.

Comment: Running just nslookup inside pod terminal and hitting enter output busybox version 1.35. How can change that. I was trying to get DNS service discovery to work in minikube.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
vagrant@kubemaster:~$ cat dnsutils.yaml
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dnsutils
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: dnsutils
    image: gcr.io/kubernetes-e2e-test-images/dnsutils:1.3
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
```

save this in yaml format and run `kubectl apply -f <filename>.yaml` and then run below command

```
vagrant@kubemaster:~$ kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup 10-40-0-2.default.pod  | tee nginx-pod

Server:     10.96.0.10
Address:    10.96.0.10#53

Name:   10-40-0-2.default.pod.cluster.local
Address: 10.40.0.2
```

It should resolve the output and save it in the file.