# Not able to nslookup kubernetes.default

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I have kubernetes cluster running on `Ubuntu 16.04`. When I run `nslookup kubernetes.default` on `master` it shows below:

```
Server:     192.168.88.21
Address:    192.168.88.21#53

** server can't find kubernetes.default: NXDOMAIN
```

Below is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 192.168.88.21
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search VISDWK.local
```

Using kubernetes version

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.1", GitCommit:"eec55b9ba98609a46fee712359c7b5b365bdd920", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-13T10:36:44Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Using weave for networking and installed using:

```
kubectl apply -f "https://cloud.weave.works/k8s/net?k8s-version=$(kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
```

`coredns` pods are running fine:

```
coredns-86c58d9df4-42xqc               1/1     Running   8         1d6h
coredns-86c58d9df4-p6d98               1/1     Running   7         1d1h
```

Below are the logs of `coredns-86c58d9df4-42xqc`

`.:53
2019-02-08T08:40:10.038Z [INFO] CoreDNS-1.2.6
2019-02-08T08:40:10.039Z [INFO] linux/amd64, go1.11.2, 756749c
CoreDNS-1.2.6
linux/amd64, go1.11.2, 756749c
 [INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = f65c4821c8a9b7b5eb30fa4fbc167769
t`

Can anyone please help me debug this issue. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

something wrong with busybox image. it works but am getting some errors after the nslookup command is run

```
[node1 ~]$ kubectl run busybox1 --image busybox --restart=Never --rm -it -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup kubernetes
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.96.0.1

*** Can't find kubernetes.svc.cluster.local: No answer
*** Can't find kubernetes.cluster.local: No answer
*** Can't find kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local: No answer
*** Can't find kubernetes.svc.cluster.local: No answer
*** Can't find kubernetes.cluster.local: No answer
/ # exit
pod "busybox1" deleted
[node1 ~]$
```

try with below image. it works perfectly. other versions are throwing some errors

## busybox:1.28

```
[node1 ~]$ kubectl run busybox1 --image busybox:1.28 --restart=Never --rm -it -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # nslookup kubernetes
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      kubernetes
Address 1: 10.96.0.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
/ # exit
pod "busybox1" deleted
```

## Test the api server from master

```
[node1 ~]$ kubectl get svc|grep kubernetes
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          2h
[node1 ~]$
[node1 ~]$ curl -k https://10.96.0.1/version
{
  "major": "1",
  "minor": "11",
  "gitVersion": "v1.11.7",
  "gitCommit": "65ecaf0671341311ce6aea0edab46ee69f65d59e",
  "gitTreeState": "clean",
  "buildDate": "2019-01-24T19:22:45Z",
  "goVersion": "go1.10.7",
  "compiler": "gc",
  "platform": "linux/amd64"
}[node1 ~]$
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you. What is the purpose of busybox in it. I am not using busybox

Comment: you wanted to test nslookup to kubernetes.default. using busybox:1.28 you can check that

Comment: Okay I got the proper response of nslookup from busybox. Does that mean coredns is working fine.?

Comment: you should get the output that is shown above for busybox:1.28. Then your cluster is working well

Comment: Yes I have got the same output as yours. But can you tell me why nslookup wasnt responding on master.? Thank you.

Comment: check my update above to see how to test api server connection from master server

Comment: Thanks, one last question, I did this curl on one of the pod and got the proper response so does that mean that the pod and its networking is running fine in cluster.?

Comment: you are good. But you should also deploy one sample web application to check application and its connectivity to backend database pod. this is to make sure that your cluster is configured correctly

Comment: nslookup for my service is working fine inside a busybox but its not working directly what is the reason?? @Ekambaram(i checked it using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52109039/nslookup-cant-resolve-kubernetes-default?rq=1)